# Calling private method inside private class inside Inner class

Tags: java, oop

Need to call a private method `foo()` of the class **Inner.Private**, where `Private` is an inner private class from the main method of the main class.
The code is something like this:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Need to invoke foo() from here
        } 

    static class Inner {
        private class Private {
            private String foo() {
                return "someString";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I  was trying to get this using Java Reflection, but I am facing issues from this approach.

My attempt to invoke the `foo()` is:

```
        Inner innerClassObject = new Inner();
        Method method = Inner.Private.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(innerClassObject);
```

But this gives a NoSuchMethodException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
default.MainClass$Inner$Private.foo()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
```

I am stuck at this point, is this achievable by Java Reflection, or any other way?

Comment: Could you please fix the brackets in your code? There are 5 opening and 6 closing brackets.

Comment: My bad, @QuantumDeveloper, thanks for pointing out. Fixed now.

Comment: There are some problems with your code, your `Inner` class is actually defined as outer, if it's what you want, then remove the 'static' modifier  since it is not allowed for outer classes.

Comment: @adxl, The code is correct, I just named the class as `Inner`, because I wanted to bring the focus on that part. There is a private class -- having a private method --  inside this class.

Comment: Yes but the class is actually defined outside `MainClass`, that's what makes it an outer class, notice the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm... why not simply `new Inner().new Private().foo()`?

Comment: Thanks, @crizzis, this actually helped to get the solution, I did not know we can even do it without Java reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this

```
Inner.Private.class
```

Instead of

```
innerClassObject.getClass()
```

For e.x:

```
public class Test {


private int foo(){
    System.out.println("Test"); 
    return 1;
}
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException, 
NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
InvocationTargetException
{
  Test innerClassObject = new Test();
    Method method = 
    innerClassObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo",null);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(innerClassObject);
}


}
```

Comment: I don't clearly know the difference in the 2 ways, but `Method method = innerClassObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo");` also gives `NoSuchMethodException`

Answer (score 0):

Why waste an instantiation just to call a method as was described?  You will inevitably want to save various instances for latter use as the classes develop.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Need to invoke foo() from here
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        Inner.Private pvt = inner.new Private();
        System.out.println(pvt.foo());
    }

    static class Inner {
        private class Private {
            private String foo() {
                return "someString";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
someString
```